# How to rig breasts

Tags: rigging

I am a brand new user to Blender and only have about a week experience. I have been playing with armatures and learning the ins and outs of blender. I have been trying to rig dynamic breasts to my mesh so they will simulate movement for a few days, and I'm running into a problem.

Sorry in advance if this has a solution already, but I have been on an endless search and can not find a solution, so I am hoping by asking I can get the proper guidance.

I can not upload my .blend right this moment, so I hope I can explain my problem well enough, that someone may be able to help. I will try and mention everything I have tried to make and help a bit easier.

Ok.  So I started off by creating a mesh with makehuman. I exported the mesh and then imported it to blender. The first thing I have done with the mesh is change the scale. When importing from MH my mesh was scaled to .1. I selected the entire mesh in object mode and opened my menu using the "N" key and set all the scale properties to "1". After I re-scaled the mesh, I applied the scale by pressing ctrl+A and apply scale/rotation (my mesh is not rotated just selected both) one thing I notice with my mesh, and I'm not sure if this is the root of the problem, but the Y axis points to the back of the mesh. I have tried to change the rotation and apply that rotation to try and fix my problem, but that has not worked.

So, I carry on with my mesh in its default location, and begin the create my armature. I am able to create a fully functioning armature with ik bones and everything. I have placed two small bones inside the breast (deform bones) and parent them to the chest bone. They control the mesh as desire. After this, I create a cube, apply a subdivision all surface, give it two views and apply the modifier. After I apply the modifier I shape the now rounded cube as desired. One properly shaped I apply the scale and rotation. After that I change the name of the cube, place it in location, and change it to a "soft body". Then I take that round cube and duplicate it by holding shift pressing D and then X and moving it into place. Once both rounded cubes are placed, I create a new one to hold the rounded "breasts". I scale that cube on the Y axis and apply the scale/rotation and move it into place. After that is completed I change my mesh and armature to "no collision" so they do not have an affect on the "breast" movement.  After creating the breasts and plate to hold them, I add three rigid body joints to each breast, for a total of 6 joints. I place two near the top of each breast and on in the middle to act as the pivots that the breasts will move on. After all this is complete, I parent the plate that holds the breasts, the the same bone the breast bones are parented to, allowing everything to move as one. Everything works great up to this point and this is where I run into trouble.

So, now I am trying to copy the transform of cube breasts, and apply them the the bones so they will control the mesh with movement. So I go into pose mode and I select the breast bone, and add "copy transform" from there I select the appropriate breast cube, and this is where my problem starts.

When end I apply the cube to the bone, it flips the bone on the Y axis, or changes its location completely and there is nothing I can seem to do to fix this. Like I said, I'm very new to blender, and it feels like I've tried everything. But in my experience it is usually a simple fix for thighs like this and I am hoping for the same.

I I have tried to flip everything using the 3D cursor on the Y axis and apply the rotation but nothing is working. Something I have notices is when I am in edit mode and select the bone within the breast and check its location, it give accurate numbers to the "global" location, but when I switch to pose mode, the locations all display 0 for their values. I have no idea if that is a factor when I try and copy the transform or not, but I feel like it might be?

Just to give as much info as I can initially. There is a blue dotted line the connects the breast mesh that I created to the plate mesh which holds the breasts. This dotted line is in the centre of the breast mesh. When I add the bone constraint and copy the transform the "world space" option flips the bone 180 on the Y and places the head of the bone at the centre location. When I change the influence it obviously rotates it back to the location I placed it within edit mode. When I switch to local space, it keeps the proper alignment on the Y axis, but totally changes the location of the bone. Pose space seems to place the head of the bone at the top of axis in the centre? And local with parent behaves similar to local.

I obviously have not tried everything or I would have a solution , it's starting to feel that way though. I will try my best to upload my .blend later if my explanation draws some blanks. And if anything can think of something I could try I would greatly appreciate it.

After typing this up I played around with this a little more. When I adjust the influence of the modifier I can see the affect on the bone when I apply the modifier. It appears the bone is rotating the head location to the centre of the cube I created for the breast and not staying in the current location. I'm hoping there is a solution that will allow me to keep the bone in the current location when I apply a modifier to it. I have tired countless things and hope someone can understand what I'm trying to say.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Y axis is supposed to point to the back. Blender uses the Z axis as the vertical axis. There are several posts about this on this site, and probably several on other sites as well. http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=y+up

Comment: https://www.jorgebernier5d.com/tutorials.html ,this tutorial is bible and verse on how to do this in blender , just a rookies opinion .

Answer (score 2):

[image: Jiggle Bones, Jiggle Bones, Jiggle all the way]

As a beginner, I would recommend you take an easier path to rig up your breasts. One jiggle bone (per breast) should suffice. Take a look at Cheece's Jiggle Armature Add-On.

https://blenderartists.org/t/jiggle-armature-2/692562

The page linked has a video tutorial, you can also check out youtube for the "Jiggle Armature" and you will find a bunch more.

It is very easy to set up and flexible, too.

Answer (score 1):

so I am very new to this but as near as I can tell it sounds  like your making this a bit more complicated than necessary , from what I can gather from what I consider the Bone_Master of Blender , https://www.jorgebernier5d.com ,his tutorial  : uglychristmassweater_tutorial files.zip Download File , the procedural appears to me like adding smaller bones at the top of the chest much like adding two more arm rigs with constraints and round cubes at the tip of the each breast to give them independent movement , also he deploys a technique of_off setting the round sphere to the edge of the cube so that the bone is able to manipulate the breast movement partly in and outside the cube with most of the sphere remaining in the squire cube and round and the movement portion outside of the cube , then adds constraints to limit the movement , then he ties the structure together to get an over-all center and each breast moves independent but also moves jointly as the chest moves, this is very over simplified and not very descriptive on the mechanics but with my limited knowledge is the best description I can give .